# ASP.NET MVC project no longer loads after updating package for Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, nuget

Just a few days ago Microsoft released an update for the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` package (version 5.3.0). I updated my packages through nuget and updated my ASP.NET MVC project going from 5.2.9 to 5.3.0.

After doing so, my project just straight up doesn't work. Once the project finishes building and opens up my web browser it just displays an error 500 directly (*This page isn't working at the moment*). No errors listed in Visual Studio or any indication in the output as to what just happened. I don't seem to reach the `application_start` as well so can't do any debugging.

- What I've tried was to re install packages for the project using the `Upgrade-Package` command from the package manager console. I've also tried manually deleting the packages from the File explorer and had Visual studio re install them. Both of which didn't work.
- Solution clean, build, rebuild doesn't work as well
- I've tried looking in the event viewer for any application logs relating to the project, no luck there.

One thing I could find was a warning from the browser dev tools console when the error 500 displays, but can't really relate it to the issue I have with the updated packages

```
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(anonymous) @ (index):6587
```

If you have ideas on what else I could check, please share. Thanks

--

Btw if its any help, the update package and its dependencies are as follows:

- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi - v 5.3.0
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost - v 5.3.0
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core - v 5.3.0
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client - v 6.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check your `Web.config`. Also, when you try to reinstall the older version: I just updated `MicroSoft.AspNet.Mvc` from 5.2.9 to 5.3.0. Changes I got in the `Web.config`:

```
<runtime>
   <assemblyBinding>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.3.0.0" newVersion="5.3.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Yes, noticed those changes in the Web.Config file when updating to the latest version. Versions seem to be correct. Nothing is out of the ordinary

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly something to do with the binding redirects. Since the auto-generated ones aren't copied to the Web.config, you can add the below section:

```
<configuration>
    ....
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <linkedConfiguration href="file:{AssemblyName}.dll.config"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
    ....
</configuration>
```

Being sure to replace {AssemblyName} with your assembly. Also remove any existing binding redirects from your Web.config.